# Request to apache2 server always redirects to /var/www (Index of /) site

Tags: apache, debian, webserver, virtualhost, document-root

I am currently trying to setup an virtual hosts following this [tutorial on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-debian-8).

The dummy-site I am trying to serve is under `/var/www/example/html/index.html`. I have not registered an official domain but setup `/etc/hosts/` to resolve example.com to the IP address of my server.

I created another conf file called `example.conf` under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and enabled it with `sudo a2ensite example.conf` and disabled the `000-default.conf`.

Now whenever I go to `example.com` in my browser I get served:

[image: this Index of page].

This is the same page I would get when directly going to the IP address of my server. Only when I got directly to `example.com/example/html` I get served the correct `index.html`.

My current config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And my `/etc/hosts` file on my laptop like this:

```
#<ip-address>   <hostname.domain.org>   <hostname>
<server-ip> example.com
```

There are some other folders inside `/var/www/` as the company I rented the server from had some maintenance sites preinstalled, but that shouldn't matter in this situation. (See edit, this did actually matter).

It feels like I am missing something obvious here, but I can't find a solution for my problem.

Edit:

The obvious thing I was missing, was that 2 additional sites where enabled by default as well.
One had the following contents:

```
# 10_froxlor_ipandport_<ip-address>.conf
# Created 28.11.2019 21:05
# Do NOT manually edit this file, all changes will be deleted after the next domain change at the panel.

<VirtualHost <ip-address>:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
 ServerName <predefined Server name>
</VirtualHost>
```

After disabling all the other sites, the request to `example.com` actually went to the right `index.html`.

I figure, that the above enabled site actually matched the request coming from my browser and showed the `www` root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious thing I was missing, was that 2 additional sites where enabled by default as well.
One had the following contents:

```
# 10_froxlor_ipandport_<ip-address>.conf
# Created 28.11.2019 21:05
# Do NOT manually edit this file, all changes will be deleted after the next domain change at the panel.

<VirtualHost <ip-address>:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
 ServerName <predefined Server name>
</VirtualHost>
```

After disabling all the other sites, the request to `example.com` actually went to the right `index.html`.

I figure, that the above enabled site actually matched the request coming from my browser and showed the `www` root directory.